# Does LoraWan protocol's Over The Air Activation run Diffie Hellman?

Tags: diffie-hellman, iot

I am looking at the LoraWan protocol specification and I want to capture the over the air activation of a device. So far I have seen the:

https://zakelijkforum.kpn.com/lora-forum-16/over-the-air-activation-otaa-8323

As it seems that it is using nonces in order to generate the key, I thought, "Hey it seems like Diffie Hellman to me."

- Is the Over the air activation in LoRaWan is as the link mentions?
- If yes, is Diffie Hellman the key exchange being used?

Comment: The specification documents are available to read. Please look at the official documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let *AppK* the Application Key. The Application Session Key (*AppSKey*) and the Network Session Key (*NwkSKey*) are generated by using only the AES algorithm without adopt the Diffie Hellman protocol.

Let us suppose that we have a Device Node that generates a 16 bits pseudorandom nonce namely *DevNonce*. This nonce is sent to the application server. The application server generates a 22-bits pseudo random nonce namely *AppNonce* that is sent to the Device Node.

The Network ID, called *NetID* is pre-shared between the entities. Moreover a standard 32-bit code (for *NwkSKey* this is 0x01, for *AppSKey* this is 0x02) is used.

Finally the resulting message is padded to 128-bits.

```
NwkSKey = aes128_encrypt(AppKey, 0x01 | AppNonce | NetID | DevNonce | pad16)
AppSKey = aes128_encrypt(AppKey, 0x02 | AppNonce | NetID | DevNonce | pad16)
```

However I advise you this link to deepen the [LoraWan Security](https://labs.mwrinfosecurity.com/assets/BlogFiles/mwri-LoRa-security-guide-1.2-2016-03-22.pdf).